# Might have been caught/ Might be caught （In a traffic jam)

Tags: word-usage, verb-forms, modality

If someone hasn't shown up, I'm guessing it is because of the traffic. Which word form should I use?

Considering that "was caught" Is an action in the past, thus:

> He might **have been** caught in the traffic jam.

Considering "is caught" is a state, which he is still in:

> He **might be caught** in the traffic jam.

Which one do you think is more likely to be used?

Comment: Your title says 'accident', but your question is about a traffic jam, A traffic jam is not an accident.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I will edit it.